# How do I fix these strange glass lighting artifacts?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I am a beginner.

How should I go about fixing this peculiar lighting inside my glass cube in this instance. I just used a normal glass cube and applied cycles to render glass materials to it.

Comment: what do you want to fix, exactly? Inside the glass you will see reflections and refractions of the scene you prepared, so, to modify it, you'll have to modify the scene (and maybe the lighting and the roughness of the glass)

Comment: Its hard to tell exactly what "artifacts" you are talking about.  The render looks like it should to me.  If you are talking about the black patches, those are just reflections of the (black) environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use a solidify modifier. When I was a beginner I used to make the mistake of thinking that glass would only be applied to the mesh and not the entire volume.